# How can I insert the same select object multiple times in HTML with different ids?

Tags: html

I have a website, which uses multiple elements which are the same (only different ids) like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="0" selected>No Interrupt</option>
  <option value="1">Interrupt on falling edge</option>
  <option value="2">Interrupt on rising edge</option>
  <option value="3">Interrupt on change</option>
</select>
```

How can I insert this select object multiple times at specific places in the HTML document using native html or javascript, for example here:

```
...
<body>
...
<div>
INSERT SELECT FROM ABOVE WITH ID 'A' HERE
</div>
...
<div>
INSERT SELECT AGAIN HERE WITH ID 'B'
</div>
...

<body>
```

I do not want to copy them each time. I want them to be defined once and inserted multiple times.

Comment: you can make use of a simple attribute provided by w3 called *w3-include* which makes use of vanillajs to inject an HTML snippet to your code.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: To be clear, note that "w3" and w3schools is not affiliated with the W3C standards body in any way, shape  or form.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **w3-include-html** to insert HTML snippets in your code.

// snippet.html

```
<h1><b>Hi, I'm a snippet</b></h1>
```

// someOther.html

```
<div w3-include-html="snippet.html"></div>
<script>
  includeHTML();
</script>
```

// script.js

```
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /* Loop through a collection of all HTML elements: */
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /* Make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name: */
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /* Remove the attribute, and call this function once more: */
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /* Exit the function: */
      return;
    }
  }
}
```